# Using Multiple Tkinter Treeview Styles in same program

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

I don't seem to be able to find the answer to this.  I am using several Tkinter Treeviews in my program.  When I change the style of one, it changes all of them.  What Am I missing? This is the code I have written for one, its repeated four times (the others with different colours)

```
style = ttk.Style()
#style.theme_use("default")
style.configure("Treeview",background="Black", foreground="White",fieldbackground="red")
style.map('Treeview', background=[('selected','#3c3737')],foreground=[('selected','white')])
my_tree = ttk.Treeview(my_canvas2,height=1000)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create custom widget styles by using `style.configure("<custom_name>.<widget_type>"...`. So, if you wanted to create a custom "Treevew" style, you would use `style.configure("MyCustom.Treeview"...)`.

You then would create a `ttk` widget and pass the custom widget style as the `style` argument, for example `my_treeview = ttk.Treeview(master, style="MyCustom.Treeview")`. Here is an example program that creates two different `ttk.TreeView`s, with different styles:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk

w = tkinter.Tk()

style = ttk.Style()
style.configure("Custom1.Treeview",background="Black", foreground="White",fieldbackground="red")
style.map('Custom1.Treeview', background=[('selected','#3c3737')],foreground=[('selected','white')])

style.configure("Custom2.Treeview",background="Greed", foreground="Purple",fieldbackground="pink")
style.map('Custom2.Treeview', background=[('selected','#3c3737')],foreground=[('selected','white')])

my_tree1 = ttk.Treeview(w, height=1000, style="Custom1.Treeview")
my_tree1.pack(side="left")

my_tree2 = ttk.Treeview(w, height=1000, style="Custom2.Treeview")
my_tree2.pack(side="right")

w.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope I would help you:

````
from tkinter import ttk, CENTER, EW
w = tkinter.Tk()
style_wear = ttk.Style()
style_wear.configure("fortree1.Treeview",background="yellow", foreground="black",fieldbackground="red")
style_wear.map('fortree1.Treeview', background=[('selected','green')],foreground=[('selected','black')])
tree02 = ttk.Treeview(w, column=("c1", "c2","c3",), show='headings', height=5,style="fortree2.Treeview")
tree02.column("# 1", anchor=CENTER, width=40)
tree02.heading("# 1", text="S/N")
tree02.column("# 2", anchor=CENTER, width=170)
tree02.heading("# 2", text="Nature of damage")
tree02.column("# 3", anchor=CENTER, width=65)
tree02.heading("# 3", text="Start")
tree02['show']='headings'
tree02.grid(row=1,column=0,columnspan=4,sticky=EW)
tree02.insert("", 'end', values=("a","a","a"))
tree02.insert("", 'end',values=("b","b","b",))
style_measurement = ttk.Style(w)
style_measurement.configure("fortree2.Treeview",background="Green", foreground="red",fieldbackground="pink")
style_measurement.map('fortree2.Treeview', background=[('selected','blue')],foreground=[('selected','white')])
tree1 = ttk.Treeview(w, show='headings', height=10,column=("c1", "c2","c3"),style="fortree1.Treeview")
tree1.column("# 1", anchor=CENTER, width=185)
tree1.heading("# 1", text="From the bottom tube")
tree1.column("# 2", anchor=CENTER, width=100)
tree1.heading("# 2", text="Original")
tree1.column("# 3", anchor=CENTER, width=100)
tree1.heading("# 3", text="Measured")
tree1.insert("", 'end',values=("a","a","a"))
tree1.insert("", 'end',values=("b","b","b"))
tree1['show']='headings'
tree1.grid(row=2,column=0,columnspan=3)
w.mainloop()```
````

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).